# android database extension not showing in file explorer

Tags: android, sqlite

I have used sqliteOpenHelper to use database, It is working ok, but i want to see tables and there data

for that I have installed [SqlLite Manager](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/) to view my table's data in file explorer. but when i reached directory data/data/[myPackage]/databases , my Database  File is present there but without any extension(.db is not written with it), and may b this [SqlLite Manager](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/) is not openning the table

*I have checked native alarm clock's database, it is opening and has extension alarms ".db"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While creating the database you can assign the extension (.sqlite or .db) but the extension is not mandatory here, it will work with/without extension. If you are interested in extension then you should specify the extension while creating the database.

For example if you have used SQLiteOpenHelper then you can use the DB_NAME as DbName.Extension as shown below:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{ 
private Context mycontext; 

//the extension may be .sqlite or .db
private static String DB_NAME = "(datbasename).sqlite";
//OR
private static String DB_NAME = "(datbasename).db";


...... other code goes here
```

Comment: thanks, that was valueable info, now sqLite Manager is also working with extension